# Ionic 2 Events are two working trouble

Tags: ionic2

I am developing a virtual market application.
I am running an event in the tab menu when I delete the cart. But this event is working twice. The first time I open the program, it only works once, but when I repeat the same operation a second time, the event works twice.
How can I solve this problem?
I Share Codes.
Cart Codes :

```js
presentConfirm(){
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title : 'Sepet Temizlensin mi?',
    message : 'Sepetteki tüm ürünleri silmek istiyor musunuz?',
    buttons : [
      {
        text : 'Hayır',
        role : 'cancel'
      },
      {
        text : 'Evet',
        handler : () => {
          this.sepetiSil();
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

```js
sepetiSil(){
  let loader = this.loader.create({
    content : "Lütfen bekleyiniz.."
  });
  let header = new Headers();
  header.append("Content-Type","application/json");
  header.append("Accept","application/json");
  var base_url = "xxxxxxxxx/xxx";
  var veri = JSON.stringify({
    BELGEID : this.globalBelgeID
  });
  loader.present();
  this.http.post(base_url, veri, header).map(res=>res.text()).subscribe(data=>{
      this.sepetArray.pop();
      this.MIKTARMODEL.pop();
      this.URUNTUTARMODEL.pop();
      this.TOPLAMTUTAR = 0;
    
 this.events.publish('sepet:sayacsifirla');
      var mesaj = "Sepet başarıyla temizlendi.";
      loader.dismissAll();
      this.mesajOlustur(mesaj);
  },(error)=>{ loader.dismissAll(); this.sepetiSil(); });
}
```

Tabs Codes:

```js
this.events.subscribe('sepet:sayacsifirla',()=>{
        this.SEPETSAYISI = 0;
        this.dizi.pop();
        this.SEPETURUNLER.pop();
        console.log(this.dizi);
        console.log("SAYAÇ SIFIRLANDI VE YÖNLENDİRİLME YAPILDI");
        this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(TabsPage);
      });
```

As you can see, the event works twice

[image: Screenshoot console]

Comment: is the http request going twice? where is `sepetiSil()` called?

Comment: I inserted it into the post presentConfirm() @suraj

Comment: and the event subscribe code is set where?

Comment: in constructor in tabpage @suraj

Comment: do you have an idea? @suraj

Comment: I have a hunch.. adding as answer

Comment: @suraj yes its work thank you

Comment: glad to hear it :).Consider accepting the answer to close the issue

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `events.subscribe` in TabsPage constructor and also you are doing:

```
this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(TabsPage);
```

This is creating a new view which seems to be adding *another* handler to the same event which means 2 handlers get executed when you click on `sepetiSil()` a second time.

You can try unsubscribing every time before setting TabsPage as root:

```
this.events.subscribe('sepet:sayacsifirla',()=>{
        this.SEPETSAYISI = 0;
        this.dizi.pop();
        this.SEPETURUNLER.pop();
        console.log(this.dizi);
        console.log("SAYAÇ SIFIRLANDI VE YÖNLENDİRİLME YAPILDI");
        this.events.unsubscribe('sepet:sayacsifirla');//here
        this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(TabsPage);
      });
```

Or use page lifecycle events to subscribe and unsubscribe to the event